# Excel VBA user event

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with Excel VBA and I have a macro that is fired everytime a specific cell is changed.  That macro affects the value and properties of many cells on the worksheet, so I used

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
[...] 'mycode
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

At the beginning and end of the macro.  Otherwise whenever I change the cell that fires the macro, the macro changes cell and thus fires itself over and over again.

I would like for the macro to be fired if I manually change a cell (without having to insert a command button that fires the macro or something similar)

Is that possible?

Thanks for the help

Comment: `being new to VBA Excel, I have no idea how to do this.` is an excuse which is not acceptable :) Have you tried anything? If yes, can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck? If not, then why?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Column =4) Then
        MsgBox ("mycell changed")
    End If
End Sub
```

This basically says if the column change occurs in Index 4 (D) then msgbox.
if you didn't have the if statement the messgbox would occur anytime a change occurs to any cell in the worksheet.